# Django-haystack - how to make only a subset of items be searchable?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have some items that I am indexing with Django-haystack (elasticsearch backend) to be searchable. This works fine, but users are able to favorite the items, and I would like users to be able to search their favorites just like they are able to search all the items. The favorite is represented with a many to many through relationship, because I need the time to be recorded when a user favorites an item. Is there any way to make just the users favorites searchable with haystack? I don't want to generate a separate index for every users favorites, because they will be reduntant as the items are the same and already indexed by the master index. Here is what my models and search index look like for reference:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):   
    faves = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, through='Favorite', null=True, related_name="faves")

class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["date"]

class GalleryIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):

    def get_model(self):
        return Gallery
```

Thanks.

Comment: This might help: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html?highlight=subset#SearchQuerySet.narrow

Comment: Will this really work for this use case? From what I can see ES stores everything as a flat document, and this is filtering by a relation(items in the users favorites). I am not storing the users that favorited an item as a array or something and including it as part of the indexing parameters. I would need to be able to filter by something like (object in user.faves)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at the RelatedSearchQuerySet (http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#relatedsearchqueryset). Be very certain to read the warning on the page about performance implications though; I just tried this and it was noticeably slower than most queries.

You'll want something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from haystack.query import RelatedSearchQuerySet
from .models import Gallery

u = User.objects.get(...)
sqs = RelatedSearchQuerySet().load_all()
sqs = sqs.load_all_queryset(Gallery, u.faves.all())
```

That should give you a SearchQuerySet containing just the user's favorites, which you can further filter and search on.